# Movie about a boy who goes back in time to stop a building from burning down

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

It's about a boy who goes back in time to save a building from getting burned down, or something like that. I think a little girl from that time was helping him, and no one from that time can see him. I think one of the family members in the past was planning on burning it down.

Anyone know what this is?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anything else you may remember? For example, when did you see this? Also don't forget to take the [tour]!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### *[The Amazing Mr. Blunden](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068200/)*

> A mysterious, very old solicitor Mr. Blunden visits Mrs. Allen and her young children in her squalid, tiny Camden Town flat and makes her an offer she cannot refuse. The family become the housekeepers to a derelict country mansion in the charge of the solicitors. One day the children meet the spirits of two other children who died in the mansion nearly a hundred years previously. The children prepare a magic potion that allows them to travel backwards in time to the era of the ghost children. Will the children be able to help their new friends and what will happen to them if they do??

From the longer synopsis:

> Lucy and James take the potion and travel back to 1818. They meet Tom who excitedly reckons they have come from America - the new world - where one day he hopes to go. They quickly realise no adults can see them, the exception being Bella who has the mind of a child. They spook her into getting her mother to release Georgie from the cellar.

....

> Lucy and James realise the nursery where Sara and Georgie sleep is above the library where the fire will start. They try unsuccessfully to get the keys off Mrs Wickens and rush outside to see Mr Wickens carrying a bundle of wood to the fire he has just started outside the library.

Comment: That was quick, Was that one you were familiar with?

Comment: Well we don't know if it's correct yet ... but yes it's a well-known British children's film.

Comment: An excellent edit @FuzzyBoots probably worthy of its own answer!

Comment: @Edlothiad: It doesn't quite cross the threshold for me. I just followed their link and copied over two paragraphs. :)

Comment: Thanks guys, it's not that old of a movie, maybe a little younger? I can't remember what time it was based in...

Comment: Within the last couple years, I saw it on tv if that helps

Comment: It's like a mystery but not, like they are trying to figure who's planning to do it to stop it...